# Simple Video Conversion for tech-ignorant client

Tags: video, video-encoding

I have a client who will be uploading videos to Expression Engine and will need to convert to MP4 before doing so. This client is largely tech- and web-ignorant so I need to make this as simple as possible.

Can you guys recommend a simple desktop conversion tool for the PC for converting videos to MP4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using MPEG Streamclip.